# Ad-like popups in android application

Tags: java, android, admob

Is it possible to have ad-like pop-ups without using 3rd party JAR (like AdMob, etc) inside my own adnroid application?

The requirement is to show a banner (referencing to a link, the ad is related with the app itself) within the android application when connected to the internet.

Thank you for your help in advance! :D

Comment: Do you want to show third party advertisements with your own library, or show a single ad for one of your related products? The first one is too big for us to help you with, but the second is much more reasonable.

Comment: Hi Kevin, not 3rd party ads but own related products. :D

Answer (score 0):

To show ad like popup you either you can use any 3rd party library or you can do it with your self using webview. Here you do not want to use third party library, so I suggest you to use **WebView**. Whatever your link contains, just show it in banner, like Javascript, Html or Ad Image, you can show it in WebView which will looks like a banner. For this you have to do one thing only and it is, you have to design webview and its position looks like Ad banner. That's it.

Comment: Will this still show the banner at the bottom of the page just liek the normal ads appear? do you have any acode i can view for reference? appreciate your help!

Comment: @ohhzumm wherever you want to put, just declare webview at the bottom of the page and show your content that's it.

Comment: will it pop up like the admob ads when connected to the internet? and be gone for quite some time?

Comment: @ohhzumm whatever action you want to perform, you can develop with your own.